# How to join 2 data tables by time interval and summarize overlapping and non-overlapping time periods by factor variable

Tags: r, data.table, overlap

I have 2 data tables, each lists periods of observation effort, and type of effort (A,B,C).
I would like to know the duration of time for the overlapping and non-overlapping periods of effort.

I've tried to do this with data.table and foverlaps, but can't figure out how to include all the non-overlapping periods.

Here is my example data. I first created 2 data tables containing periods of effort. My dataset will include periods of time when a single observer is on effort.

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

# times have been edited so not fixed to minute intervals - to make more realistic
set.seed(13)
EffortType = sample(c("A","B","C"), 100, replace = TRUE)
On = sample(seq(as.POSIXct('2016/01/01 01:00:00'), as.POSIXct('2016/01/03 01:00:00'), by = "1 sec"), 100, replace=F)
Off = On + minutes(sample(1:60, 100, replace=T))
Effort1 = data.table(EffortType, On, Off)

EffortType2 = sample(c("A","B","C"), 100, replace = TRUE)
On2 = sample(seq(as.POSIXct('2016/01/01 12:00:00'), as.POSIXct('2016/01/03 12:00:00'), by = "1 sec"), 100, replace=F)
Off2 = On2 + minutes(sample(1:60, 100, replace=T))
Effort2 = data.table(EffortType2, On2, Off2)

#prep for using foverlaps
setkey(Effort1, On, Off)
setkey(Effort2, On2, Off2)
```

Then I use foverlaps to find where the effort overlaps. I've set nomatch=NA, but this just gives me the right outer join. I would like the full outer join. And so i wonder what the more appropriate function would be.

```
matches = foverlaps(Effort1,Effort2,type="any",nomatch=NA)
```

I've continued on here to show how I've tried to determine the duration of all the overlapping and non-overlapping shift times. But I don't think I've got this part correct either.

```
# find start and end of intersection of all shifts
matches$start = pmax(matches$On, matches$On2, na.rm=T)
matches$end = pmin(matches$Off, matches$Off2, na.rm=T)

# create intervals and find durations
matches$int = interval(matches$start, matches$end)
matches$dur = as.duration(matches$int)
```

I would then like sum up the amount of observation effort time for each grouping of "EffortType"

And end up with something like this (numbers are examples only because I have not managed to figure out how to calculate this correctly, even in excel)

```
EffortType  Duration(in minutes)
A           10
B           20
C           12
AA          8
BB          6
CC          1
AC          160
AB          200
BC          150
```

Comment: You should add some library(...) calls. `minutes` isn't in base R

Comment: There are overlaps within `Effort1` and `Effort2`. How should these be handled? Should these be collapsed by `EffortType`?

Comment: I've edited how times are created in the example to make it more realistic. It is possible that there may be an overlap between Effort1 and Effort2. This should be included in the duration summary eg. AA, BB, or CC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the entire answer (see last paragraph).. but I think this will get you what you want.

```
library( data.table )
library( lubridate )

set.seed(13)
EffortType = sample(c("A","B","C"), 100, replace = TRUE)
On = sample(seq(as.POSIXct('2016/01/01 01:00:00'), as.POSIXct('2016/01/03 01:00:00'), by = "15 mins"), 100, replace=T)
Off = On + minutes(sample(1:60, 100, replace=T))
Effort1 = data.table(EffortType, On, Off)

EffortType2 = sample(c("A","B","C"), 100, replace = TRUE)
On = sample(seq(as.POSIXct('2016/01/01 12:00:00'), as.POSIXct('2016/01/03 12:00:00'), by = "15 mins"), 100, replace=T)
Off = On + minutes(sample(1:60, 100, replace=T))
Effort2 = data.table(EffortType2, On, Off)

#create DT of minutes, spanning your entire period.
dt.minutes <- data.table( On = seq(as.POSIXct('2016/01/01 01:00:00'), as.POSIXct('2016/01/03 12:00:00'), by = "1 mins"), 
                          Off = seq(as.POSIXct('2016/01/01 01:00:00'), as.POSIXct('2016/01/03 12:00:00'), by = "1 mins") + 60 )

#prep for using foverlaps
setkey(Effort1, On, Off)
setkey(Effort2, On, Off)

#overlap join both efforts on the dt.minutes. note the use of "within" an "nomatch" to throw away minutes without events.

m1 <- foverlaps(dt.minutes, Effort1 ,type="within",nomatch=0L)
m2 <- foverlaps(dt.minutes, Effort2 ,type="within",nomatch=0L)

#bind together
result <- rbindlist(list(m1,m2))[, `:=`(On=i.On, Off = i.Off)][, `:=`(i.On = NULL, i.Off = NULL)]

#cast the result
result.cast <- dcast( result, On + Off ~ EffortType, value.var = "EffortType")
```

results in

```
head( result.cast, 10)

#                      On                 Off A B C
#  1: 2016-01-01 01:00:00 2016-01-01 01:01:00 1 0 1
#  2: 2016-01-01 01:01:00 2016-01-01 01:02:00 1 0 1
#  3: 2016-01-01 01:02:00 2016-01-01 01:03:00 1 0 1
#  4: 2016-01-01 01:03:00 2016-01-01 01:04:00 1 0 1
#  5: 2016-01-01 01:04:00 2016-01-01 01:05:00 1 0 1
#  6: 2016-01-01 01:05:00 2016-01-01 01:06:00 1 0 1
#  7: 2016-01-01 01:06:00 2016-01-01 01:07:00 1 0 1
#  8: 2016-01-01 01:07:00 2016-01-01 01:08:00 1 0 1
#  9: 2016-01-01 01:08:00 2016-01-01 01:09:00 1 0 1
# 10: 2016-01-01 01:09:00 2016-01-01 01:10:00 1 0 1
```

Sometimes a event occurs 2-3 times within the same minute, like

```
#                     On                 Off A B C
#53: 2016-01-02 14:36:00 2016-01-02 14:37:00 2 2 3
```

Not sure on how you want to sum that...

If you can treat them as a single minute, then:

```
> sum( result.cast[A>0 & B==0, C==0, ] )
[1] 476
> sum( result.cast[A==0 & B>0, C==0, ] )
[1] 386
> sum( result.cast[A==0 & B==0, C>0, ] )
[1] 504
> sum( result.cast[A>0 & B>0, C==0, ] )
[1] 371
> sum( result.cast[A==0 & B>0, C>0, ] )
[1] 341
> sum( result.cast[A>0 & B==0, C>0, ] )
[1] 472
> sum( result.cast[A>0 & B>0, C>0, ] )
[1] 265
```

will do the trick to get duration in minutes, I think (although this can probably be done in a much smarter way)

Comment: Your solution brought to light a weakness with my example dataset - I shouldn't end up with events occurring 2-3 times within the same minute as your results point out. Have changed the example data to make more realistic and avoid this.

Comment: @heatherr  if this is the answer for your problem, please let me know by accepting the answer. If not, please indicate where remaining problems are.

Comment: Would you please explain why i.On and i.Off are assigned to On and Off when binding together? I'm not sure why we wouldn't instead just delete the On and Off columns. Is it to keep the names neat?"

Comment: @heatherr, yup.. it's just to keep the names neat.